# JSON Macro inception validation throws NullPointerException

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm trying to use JSON-inception for vaildating a request inside a RESTful application. But it seems that either the JSON-request or the JSON-inception logic is faulty.

some fragments of the necessary code(simplified):

`(JsPath \ "geometry").readNullable[Geometry]`

```
case class Geometry(
    circle : Option[Circle]
)

object Geometry{
    implicit val circleReads: Format[Circle] = Json.format[Circle]
}

case class Circle(radius: Double)
```

The JSON-String i am using:

```
"geometry":{
    "circle":{"radius":1.1},
}
```

Posting this request is resulting in a NullPointerException at this place

```
request.body.validate[Calculation]
```

Tests showed that the validation recognizes the "circle"-path in the JSON-string because there is no reaction to other names at this point.

Am i missing something or do i misunderstand the JSON-inception approach? The playframework version is 2.4.6.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")